# method.invoke throwing Value cannot be null exception

Tags: c#, reflection, task

I've this code.

```
MethodInfo method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Run");
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)method.Invoke(obj, null));
```

I can confirm that obj and method are valid.  I can see that the function Run is being invoked as well.  But after the method Run completes, I'm getting the below exception :

```
Message = "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: action"
```

I'm unable to figure out, which "action" parameter is being referred to here since the function Run doesn't return/accept arguments.  Here's the Run method if it helps :

```
public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm here");

        }
```

Comment: why are you casting method to Action?

Comment: try `method?.Invoke(obj, null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the parameter to your invoke which cannot be null, it's your parameter to Task.Factory.StartNew.

Just do:

```
Task.Run(() => method.Invoke(obj, null));
```